# Name Decoration of dll function, #pragma comment(linker...)

Tags: c++, dll, export

I've got 2 Question concerning exported function names.
I walked through the MSDN Example:

[Creating and Using a Dynamic Link Library (C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636(v=vs.110).aspx)

1. Why can I access the dll function with their undecorated name? There is no `.def`File. As MSDN states : 
   *"dllexport of a C++ function will expose the function with C++ name mangling"* I am wondering about why this works.
2. If I remove the `__declspec(dllexport)` resp. the macro and use instead a

   ```
   #pragma comment(linker, "/EXPORT:"__FUNCTION__"="__FUNCDNAME__)
   ```

   within the function body e.g.:

   ```
    double __stdcall ExternalAdd(double arg1, double arg2)
    {
    #pragma comment(linker, "/EXPORT:"__FUNCTION__"="__FUNCDNAME__)
         return arg1 + arg2;
   }
   ```

   I get a linker error. Why?

`dumpbin /Exports` on the dll shows:

```
ExternalAdd = @ILT+720(?ExternalAdd@@YGNNN@Z)
```

`dumpbin /Headers` on the lib shows:

```
Symbol name  : ExternalAdd
...
Name         : ExternalAdd
```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you dump the library to check if the function is actually being exported and if it is what the name is?

Comment: Neither of the examples you pointed out are part of the example linked. As for 1, you cannot access a function with its undecorated name. The decorated name comes from the function declaration (namespace, class ect) so when you include the header file in implicite linking the compiler knows what to look for in the import.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious the non working with the linker command shows: 
ExternalAdd = @ILT+230(?ExternalAdd@@YGNNN@Z)
The working one with __declspec(dllexport) shows: 
?ExternalAdd@@YGNNN@Z = @ILT+230(?ExternalAdd@@YGNNN@Z)

Comment: @Andre `1.Why can I access the dll function with their undecorated name?`  You usually can't do this.  What is helping you out here is the linker.  Try and access that function using a different compiler, say gcc, or from another language, say C#, VB, etc.  You will see that you must access the function by its decorated name.  That's where the .DEF file comes into play.